# How to give a client's state by time

Tags: oracle, plsql

```sql
Table t_customer_statistics
trx_date - transaction date
cuid - id person(divide prospect and client)
lifecycle_status - this column must be filled
```

I need to give status to a client based on his condition

1. acquired - this month was the very first transaction
2. existing - there was a transaction last month
3. reactivated - there was no transaction last month
4. sleeping - there has been no transaction for the last 90 days (there have been no subsequent ones since the last transaction, more than 90 days)
   I roughly made a code like this

```sql
UPDATE t_customer_statistics
SET Lifecycle_status =
case
when to_char (trunc (trx_date, 'mm'), 'mm.yyyy') = to_char (trunc (sysdate, 'mm'), 'mm.yyyy') then 'acquired'
when to_char (trunc (trx_date, 'mm'), 'mm.yyyy') = to_char (trunc (sysdate, 'mm') - 1, 'mm.yyyy') then 'existing'
when to_char (trunc (trx_date, 'mm'), 'mm.yyyy') = to_char (trunc (sysdate, 'mm') - 40, 'mm.yyyy') then 'reactivated'
when to_char (trunc (trx_date, 'mm'), 'mm.yyyy') <to_char (trunc (sysdate, 'mm') - 90, 'mm.yyyy') then 'sleeping'
end
```

but when they gave me an example, if the client made the first transaction and then fell asleep, then he has two states in the end, and sleeping must be separated so that there is a separate
PS. must be considered by transaction from the first and last

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table(s); the DML (`INSERT`) statement for the sample data in those tables that is representative or your issue; a complete PL/SQL script or SQL query that we can run (rather than your snippet); and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `MERGE` statement like this:

```sql
MERGE INTO clients dst
USING (
  SELECT rowid rid,
         LEAD(dt, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS prev_dt,
         LAG(dt, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS next_dt
  FROM   clients
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET status = CASE
               WHEN prev_dt IS NULL
               THEN 'acquired'
               WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(dst.dt, 'MM'), TRUNC(src.prev_dt)) <= 1
               THEN 'existing'
               ELSE 'reactivated'
               END
               ||
               CASE
               WHEN COALESCE(src.next_dt, SYSDATE) >= dst.dt + INTERVAL '90' DAY
               THEN ', sleeping'
               END;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clients (id, dt, status ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-01', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-02-01', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-01', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-05-01', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-09-01', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-01', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-01' + INTERVAL '91' DAY, CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL;
```

Then the result of the `MERGE` is:

> | ID | DT | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-20 | acquired |
> | 1 | 01-FEB-20 | existing |
> | 1 | 01-MAR-20 | existing |
> | 1 | 01-MAY-20 | reactivated, sleeping |
> | 1 | 01-SEP-20 | reactivated |
> | 1 | 01-OCT-20 | existing, sleeping |
> | 1 | 31-DEC-20 | reactivated, sleeping |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=671a233d926cb0a3459952bbf72c2f1f)*

Comment: What if I need to replace the previous status with sleeping?